# Breaking data into 15 min blocks (code sense check)

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Using SQL Server 2014, is there a more sensible way of grouping my data into 15 minute blocks? I wrote the query below which works but seems unnecessarily complicated. Hopefully someone out there has come up with a simpler way. The [Start Time] field is (datetime, not null).

```
Select 
 left(cast(concat([Hour],':',[Minute]) as time),5) as [15 Min Block]
,sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),1,0)) as [Calls Answered]
 From
(
Select
[activation ID]
,DATEPART(hh,[start time]) as [Hour],
(select case 
when datepart(mi,[Start Time]) between 0 and 14 then '00'
when datepart(mi,[Start Time]) between 15 and 29 then '15'
when datepart(mi,[Start Time]) between 30 and 44 then '30'
when datepart(mi,[Start Time]) between 45 and 59 then '45'
else 'error' end) as [Minute]
 from InboundCallsView
where [start time] > '2016-10-05') as T join InboundCallsView on t.[Activation ID] = InboundCallsView.[Activation ID]
Group by concat([Hour],':',[Minute])
order by [15 Min Block]
```

Comment: you could use the ..dateadd(n,15 * FLOOR(datediff(n, 0,[Start Time]) / 15),0).. in the query where you use the existing calc, it could shrink the query a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of a CASE work it out in one go with

```
select Right('0' + CAST(FLOOR(datepart(mi,[Start Time]) / 15.0) * 15 as nvarchar(2)),2)
```

you've also got other options, such as using a recursive CTE to generate all time slots needed in 15 minute intervals, if you wanted - some people prefer the join method you've adopted though

here is the whole query with the calc in it

```
Select 
 left(cast(concat([Hour],':',[Minute]) as time),5) as [15 Min Block]
,sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),1,0)) as [Calls Answered]
 From
(
Select
[activation ID]
,DATEPART(hh,[start time]) as [Hour],
(select Right('0' + CAST(FLOOR(datepart(mi,[Start Time]) / 15.0) * 15 as nvarchar(2)),2)) as [Minute]
 from InboundCallsView
where [start time] > '2016-10-05') as T join InboundCallsView on t.[Activation ID] = InboundCallsView.[Activation ID]
Group by concat([Hour],':',[Minute])
order by [15 Min Block]
```

---

....HERE IS ANOTHER TRICK FOR YOU

```
...Group by dateadd(n,15 * FLOOR(datediff(n, 0,[Start Time]) / 15),0)
```

.....JUST TRY THAT AS A GROUP BY ON ANY DATE GROUPING

Comment: You can even do away with the floor: Group By dateadd(n,15 * (datediff(n, 0,[Start Time]) / 15),0)

Comment: @SteveFord I guess you can due to integer divide!  I'd be a bit scared to risk it.

Comment: AndrewDeighton no need to be afraid - this is what the SQL Server documentation says "If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated." from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx